# R: ggplot2 Barplot for binomial outcome

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to create a barplot with ggplot2 that plots the percentage for a binomial outcome. Here is the data that I have:

```
IndividualID         Pass               Group
001                  Yes                Group1
002                  Yes                Group1
003                  No                 Group1
004                  Yes                Group2
005                  No                 Group2
006                  No                 Group2
007                  Yes                Group3
008                  Yes                Group3
009                  Yes                Group3
```

Ideally I'd like to create something similar to this plot (created from a different data set):

[image]

Edit: I have tried the following with no luck.

```
p<-ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Group, y=Pass)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = 'fill', fill="steelblue")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? You are more likely to receive a useful answer if you present a specific problem, instead of asking us to write you free code.

Comment: in your data there is no year. Where do you get the year from?

Comment: @Onyambu I was not able to generate a plot. I am using this as an example, where 'Year' would be replaced by 'Group'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be a direct way to do this in ggplot but here is one way preparing the data before plotting.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  count(Group, Pass) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n) * 100) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Group, n, fill = Pass, label = paste0(round(n, 2), "%")) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(position=position_stack(0.5))
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(IndividualID = 1:9, Pass = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Group1", 
"Group2", "Group3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA,-9L))
```

Comment: Nice, a rare `ggplot() + aes()` sighting in the wild!